# Can I add attribute to "read more"?

Tags: html, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am new to Wordpress and I want to know that can I add attributes to "read more" links.

```
<?php the_content('Read more'); ?>
//This creates the "read more" link
<a href="/" class="read-more">Read more</a>
```

So I want to add a class to it, but I don't know how to do it. Please help.

p.s. and I don't want to use JavaScript, because it will be very ugly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Though I am not supporter of changing the core functions, you can do it by editing `get_the_content` function in `wp-includes/post-template.php`:

```
function get_the_content($more_link_text = null, $stripteaser = 0) {
    // ...
    $output .= apply_filters( 'the_content_more_link', ' <a href="' . get_permalink() . "#more-{$post->ID}\" class=\"more-link whatever-you-want\">$more_link_text</a>", $more_link_text );
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Doing that puts you on a upgrade treadmill. Any time that file is updated in WordPress you'd have to re-apply the changes. Much better would be to define your own function in the [function file](http://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development#Functions_File)

Comment: @Derek don't be surprised if WordPress updates break your site. Modifying the core files is a very fragile practice.

Comment: @steveax, Thanks for the comment, I will be aware of that.

Answer (score 0):

You can't add a class directly to the link, but you can add a span inside of the link. From the [WordPress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Customizing_the_Read_More):

```
<?php the_content('<span class="moretext">...on the edge of
your seat? Click here to solve the mystery.</span>'); ?>
```

Comment: I need to add a class to the link itself... not inside it.

Comment: @Derek why? anything you do styling-wise to the link, you can do to the span. In any event, if you really need to do that, you'd have to write your own function to deal with the content, or perhaps there's a plugin out there that does it.

Comment: I am using HTML5 popState in my website, and I use class names to detect which link will use AJAX, and I want to make the "read more" link to use ajax.

Comment: @Derek A few thoughts... if the built in class (`read-more`) isn't a narrow enough selection, perhaps you could use the [generated page classes](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/body_class) or a container class in addition: `.home .read-more`. Or to assign click handlers to the links use something like: `$('.my-span-class').parent()`.